# I am the original inventor. Is it possible to find from USPTO PAIR the expiration of this pending patent?

Tags: ownership, priority, assignment, child-application

In reference to the patent: [US20160095523](https://www.google.com/patents/US8613706)

The 2 granted patents associated with this application are : [US8613706](https://www.google.com/patents/US8613706) and [US9332914](https://www.google.com/patents/US9332914) have been assigned to : VASCULAR SOLUTIONS, INC by me. Phil Langston.  This latest work is a child patent application.  I am just not sure what the expiration date of the new patent if granted will be.

Can you help me know from the [Public Pair Information](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)?

Thank You

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail about your relationship to the application? For example, have you assigned your rights away? If so, the assignee would have full control over what happens with any patent that grants from this application.

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't find expiration dates on patents or in the Public Pair. This is unfortunate. Unless there is an [extension](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-2700.html), the patents cited will expire 20 years from their priority date. For both of these patents that should be March 10th, 2024. Similarly, any patent arising from the published application US 2016-0095523 will also expire no later than March 10th, 2024, because that published application is a continuation of the original abandoned application 10/797,593 filed on 3-10-2004. Of course, all three patents could expire sooner than 3-10-24, for reasons like unpaid maintenance fees.

Comment: @jdpatent  Many thanks for the useful edit.

Answer (score 0):

Phil;

US20160095523 has a listed status: Response to Non-Final Office Action Entered and Forwarded to Examiner as of 04-27-2016. So it's not quite yet a patent and may not become one.

Your examiner is KAREN E TOTH. 07-22-2016 Information Disclosure Statement considered.

As you may know yourself from the [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site there is a wealth of information.

If this helps answer your question please mark it as answered and or upvote the answer.

Comment: Although this is useful as guidance, an actual answer would be even better. I'm not a lawyer, but isn't it a logical assumption that should this application ever get approved, the expiration date would be 20 years from the priority date of March 10, 2004?